# Why is main function on Objective-C looks like in C?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I have created Hello World project and saw

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

But why? Should function definition should look something like

```
(int)main:(int)argc
argv:(const char *[])argv
```

If it is possible to write function defitions in usual way, why ever somebody want to use that strange syntax like here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_functions.htm

Comment: Objective-C is an object layer built on top of C. That's why all C functionality it still there. C *functions* and Objective-C *methods* are different things. Objective-C is older than C++. C++ went in another direction, creating a whole new language.
The syntax is not strange at all, it's only different from the C syntax which was later adopted by Java and other languages, therefore becoming more common.
Asking why use objects is a strange question.

Comment: You should probably try a different sort of programming language like Prolog or Lisp to reconsider what is strange :) Note that Objective-C was built on a whole different paradigm. Calling a method means that a message is being sent between objects. That's why you can even call methods that don't exist.

Comment: @Sulthan I can say that `C#` and `Swift` are whole new languages, but `C++` is not. If you work with C's libraries in C++ you will not see the difference.

Comment: @Cy-4AH It's true you can combine them but they are considered to be separate languages. Objective-C is always just a layer on top of C and you can actually change the C dialect. Objective-C gets actually translated to C function calls. That allows things like method swizzling to be possible.
Anyway, Objective-C syntax is 40 years old and compared to other languages of that era, like Smalltalk, Basic, Pascal etc. the syntax is not strange at all. The C-syntax got only more popular with Java in 1993 and later with javascript.

Comment: @Sulthan let's put aside different interpretations of "strangeness". My question is why some functions are written in "old" syntax and others are written in "new" (please, don't discuss novelty definition)? Your answer is to distinguish "methods" and "functions" and that "new" syntax is used for "methods" only? Can we use "new" syntax for functions like `main` too?

Comment: @Dims Okey, please, try to distinguish between C functions (free functions) and methods on objects. The entry point is a free function, generally used to create the first object on which you will run everything else. Objective-C is the object layer and Objective-C syntax is used only for methods (messages) on objects. For example, on iOS the `main` function is usually generated for you, calling the native `UIApplicationMain(...)` function which delegates everything else to objects (e.g. `UIApplication`). Since `NSLog` is supposed to be called from both C and Obj-C code, it's also a C function.